# How to insert multidimensional array values into a single row in CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this problem with my code converting my multidimensional array to csv.

This is the structure of my array

```
Array (
        [vbas31] => 
                Array ( [enabled] => Array ( [0] => NO ) 
                        [registered] => Array ( [0] => NO ) ) 
        [bnmsa1] => 
                Array ( [enabled] => Array ( [0] => YES ) 
                        [registered] => Array ( [0] => NO )
                        [compromised] => Array ( [0] => NO ) )
      )
```

and I want to save it to a csv file for reporting purposes, like this:

```
vbas31, enabled, no, registered, no
bnmsa1, enabled, yes, registered, no, compromised, no
```

What I did in my code is something like this:

```
$file = fopen('testfile.csv','w');
$keysarr = array_keys($jsonArr);

for($i = 0; $i < count($jsonArr); $i++) {
    foreach($jsonArr[$keysarr[$i]] as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " : " . $value[0] . "<br>";
    
    }
    $new_line = [$keysarr[$i], $key, $value[0]];


    fputcsv($file, $new_line);
}

fclose($file);
```

But the output is not what I want, and here's the output that is generated by my code:

```
vbas31, registered, no
bnmsa1, compromised, no
```

It only gets the last data from the array. Can I ask what's the problem with my code and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of nested loops, as well as provided answers but look at this:

**Your array:**

```
$yourArray = [
    'bnas31' => [
            'enabled' => [0 => 'NO'],
            'registered' => [0 => 'NO']
    ],
    'bnmsa1' => [
        'enabled' => [0 => 'YES'],
        'registered' => [0 => 'NO'],
        'compromised' => [0 => 'NO']
    ]
];
```

**Code:**

```
foreach($yourArray as $key1 => $value1) {
    $row = $key1;
    $line = [$key1];
    foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
        $row .= ','.$key2.','.$value2[0];
        $line = array_merge($line, [$key2, $value2[0]]);
    }
    echo $row.'<br>';
}
```

You can use another `foreach` inside your other `foreach`. :)
You can just add the key first to the new line, and then iterate on rest of the elements and add those as well.
The `$row` variable is just for checking the result.

The code is so simple you should be able to analyze it by yourself.

The result of the above code is:

```
bnas31,enabled,NO,registered,NO
bnmsa1,enabled,YES,registered,NO,compromised,NO
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

> what's the problem with my code and what I'm doing wrong?

Your code is only *saving* the last element of each nested array because your `fputcsv()` is only happening for the last element of that nested array - it happens outside that last, inner loop.  Move it inside, where your `echo` is, and [it will work](https://3v4l.org/sUDql#v7.4.29).

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($jsonArr); $i++) {
    foreach($jsonArr[$keysarr[$i]] as $key => $value) {
        // Inside inner loop - this works
        // echo $keysarr[$i] . ": " . $key . ", " . $value[0] . "\n";
    }
    // Outside inner loop - only shows last element because we only
    // get here after the inner loop over the nested array has 
    // finished.  At that time the variables are set to whatever 
    // they were at the end of the last iteration - the last element.
    echo $keysarr[$i] . ": " . $key . ", " . $value[0] . "\n";
}
```

Having said that, your looping is a bit more complicated than it needs to be, here's a simpler version, and [a working example](https://3v4l.org/d2f3Z#v7.4.29):

```
$file = fopen('testfile.csv','w');

foreach ($jsonArr as $index => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $array) {

        // Some debug output
        echo $index . ": " . $key . ", " . $array[0] . "\n";

        // And save your line
        $line = [$index, $key, $array[0]];
        fputcsv($file, $line);
    }
}

fclose($file);
```